# How to set text field values into table row in jquery..?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I Have input text  field like this,

```
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Customer Name :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputCusomerName" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
              placeholder="Enter customer name">
          </div>
```

If I added some text into this text field and I need to set the same text vale in into my table row (When I press the add button),

```
      <div class="col-sm col-two">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <tr>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td id="tblCusName"></td>
          </tr>
       </div>
```

And Heare is my jquery funtion,

```
<script>
   $('#btnBuy').click(function(){
     var custName = $('#InputCusomerName').val();
      $('#tblCusName').val(custName )
   });
  </script>
```

But This function is not working..
Can You Help Me With That Problem..?
Thank You Very Much..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.val()` is for reading or setting the value of a user input. For a text element, use `.text()`.

```
$('#btnBuy').click(function(){
    var custName = $('#InputCusomerName').val();
    $('#tblCusName').text(custName )
});
```

Comment: Thank You For Your Answer..!